# how to merge column1 with columns2 in database with sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to merge 2 columns as 1 but not as UNION does but I want to merge this :

```
Id | FirstName | LastName 
-------------------------
1  | Madian    |  Aziz
2  | Jim       |  Gordon
-------------------------
```

Into this :

```
Id | FullName
-----------------
1  | Madian Aziz
2  | Jim Gordon
-----------------
```

with one space " " between the 2 columns.

NOTE: THE 2 COLUMNS ARE IN THE SAME TABLE AND THEY HAVE THE SAME ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `concat()`.  I would use `concat_ws()`:

```
select id, concat_ws(' ', firstname, lastname) as fullname
from t;
```

The nice thing about `concat_ws()` is that it handles `NULL` values in either column.

EDIT:

You can put the above logic in a view, if you want to fetch the results.

Although you can add a full name column:

```
alter table add fullname varchar(255);

update t
    set fullname = concat_ws(' ', firstname, lastname);
```

However, MySQL does not let you keep the columns in sync.  Other databases support a construct called computed columns, but not MySQL.  Your best bet is to use a view for accessing the table.

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for :) .. one thing can i concat the 2 columns in the database forever not just as a result ?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has `concat()` for concatenation.

```
select concat(FirstName, ' ', LastName) from tablename
```

ANSI SQL has `||`, e.g. `FirstName || ' ' || LastName`. (And others have `+`.)

Answer (score 0):

in Mysql you can use concat

```
select concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullname from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'CONCAT' operation. Check this tutorial here : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Caution:** One potential problem in using `CONCAT`.

`CONCAT(str1,str2,str3,.....,strn) returns NULL if any of the string is NULL`.

In your case if `firstname/lastname is NULL` then `CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) will return NULL`.

So,better check NULL before concatenating.

**Solution:**

`SELECT CONCAT(IFNULL(FirstName,''), ' ', IFNULL(LastName,'')) FROM tablename ;`

**OR**

`SELECT CONCAT(COALESCE(FirstName,''), ' ', COALESCE(LastName,'')) FROM tablename ;`